# error mounting truecrypt disk with cryptsetup

Tags: cryptsetup, truecrypt

Trying to use `cryptsetup` to mount a drive encrypted with truecrypt.

Doing this:

```
sudo cryptsetup open --type tcrypt --readonly /dev/sdc1 encrypted_drive
```

and then typing the passphrase gives me:

```
Activation is not supported for 4096 sector size.
```

**What does this error mean, and how can I mount my truecrypt volume?**

Useful information:

- The drive was encrypted with truecrypt 7.1a
- The machine trying to do this is booted into a live USB version of ubuntu, specifically ubuntu 14.04.01, i386 desktop version.
- `cryptsetup --version` yields `cryptsetup 1.6.1`
- removing the `--readonly` option produces no change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cryptsetup` expects the sector size to be `512`, but in your case it seems to be `4096`, since that is what truecrypt does for devices with physical/logical sector size of `4096`. This information is stored in the TrueCrypt header, you can also see it with `cryptsetup tcryptDump`.

The Linux version of `truecrypt` mounts such containers fine like so:

```
truecrypt /dev/sdc1 /mnt/somewhere
```

According to `dmsetup` it still uses regular encryption regardless of sector size, so this is a limitation of `cryptsetup` itself. You could open an issue for it on the cryptsetup issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/issues/list

Comment: I filed https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/580. A patch is attached on the issue; you can clone the Gitlab repo, patch in the patch, install the dependencies mentioned in the issue, then build with `./autogen.sh  && ./configure && make`

Answer (score 0):

If is not possible to use `cryptsetup` with 4096-byte sector devices then it may be a work-around to create a dummy device and use `cryptsetup` with that one:

```
sectors=$(blockdev --getsz /dev/sdc1)
echo "0 $((sectors-1)) linear /dev/sdc1 0" | dmsetup create dummy512bytes-sdc1
cryptsetup open --type tcrypt --readonly /dev/mapper/dummy512bytes-sdc1 encrypted_drive
```

Comment: The problem is not the device itself, but the Truecrypt metadata. The sector size is specified in the header, and set to `4096` at the time of creation. Your workaround may convince Truecrypt to create a new container with 512 instead of 4096 so cryptsetup will be able to open it; but won't help for existing containers...

Comment: @frostschutz Strange piece of software... But it would work if the 4096 was overwritten with 512 in the header?

Comment: The header is encrypted; just patch `cryptsetup` (set sector size to 512 at the end of `read_phdr()`). That happens to work for me, but may be coincidence. The data offset calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me. Trying to mount the volume with truecrypt as @frostschutz suggested produced the unhelpful error:

```
ParameterIncorrect at TrueCrypt::CoreUnix::MountVolume:443
```

and Veracrypt said:

```
ParameterIncorrect at VeraCrypt::CoreUnix::MountVolume:477
```

so here is what I did instead: I dumped the Truecrypt master key with the command:

```
cryptsetup tcryptDump /dev/...
```

Which gave me a poorly formatted file with the master key block. After removing all the line breaks and spaces to get a 128 character hexademical key, I loaded it into dmsetup with the command:

```
echo "0 5860532912 crypt aes-xts-plain64 <128-character-master-key> 256 /dev/sdh 256" | dmsetup create test
```

This table is in the format:

```
<start sector> <sector count> crypt <cipher> <key> <iv_offset> <device path> <offset> [<#opt_params> <opt_params>]
```

Source: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMCrypt

Edit the `<sector count>` by taking the total number of sectors on the device from `fdisk -lu` and subtract the offset. Update the rest of the fields to match `tcryptDump`. Echo the resulting table into `dmsetup` and hope it works!

If the key is correct, running `mount /dev/mapper/test /mnt/...` will work.